# Assets field within Playa field + EE 2.7.1 causing template code to display on front end

Tags: ee2, assets, playa, ee2-upgrades

I just upgraded EE to 2.7.1 and am having problems with my Playa (4.4.5) fields that pull in Assets (2.1.4) data. I have a 'homepage' channel with a Playa field that pulls articles from a 'features' channel, which includes an Assets field for (a single) image.  Pulling any data from the Assets field (e.g., {url}) causes the template code for the Playa field to display, as if the parser has choked.

For example, this works fine (without the Assets field):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="homepage"}
        {home_features}
            <article>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <p>{feature_summary}</p>
                <a href="{page_url}">more info</a>
            </article>
        {/home_features}    
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But this (stripped-down version) doesn't:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="homepage"}
        {home_features}
            <article>
                {feature_photo}<img src="{url}" >{/feature_photo} {!-- this is the Assets field --}
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <p>{feature_summary}</p>
                <a href="{page_url}">more info</a>
            </article>
        {/home_features}    
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

which displays the following on the page:

{home_features}

**Homepage**

more info

{/home_features}

('Homepage' is the title of the homepage channel entry)

Assets fields seem to be working fine elsewhere on the site, just not within Playa fields.  I did sync directories and update indexes, fyi.

Help?  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being an issue with variable namespacing -- the following worked:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="homepage"}
        {home_features var_prefix="feature"}
            <article>
                {feature:feature_photo var_prefix="file"}<img src="{file:url}" >{/feature:feature_photo} {!-- this is the Assets field --}
                <h1>{feature:title}</h1>
                <p>{feature:feature_summary}</p>
                <a href="{feature:page_url}">more info</a>
            </article>
        {/home_features}    
{/exp:channel:entries}
```